# operation not supported for recvmsg()

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, file-descriptor

iam trying to pass the file descriptor between two processes using sendmsg, recvmsg functions..

Iam doing it by creating the socket in unix domain.

When i execute it iam getting the operation not supported error for recvmsg, it is working fine with sendmsg..

the following is the code..

```
    struct sockaddr_un serveraddr;
if((sfd=socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,0))<0)
{
    perror("socket() failed");
    unlink(SERVER_PATH);
    exit(0);
}
memset(&serveraddr, 0, sizeof(serveraddr));
serveraddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strcpy(serveraddr.sun_path, SERVER_PATH);
if((rc = bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, SUN_LEN(&serveraddr)))<0)
{
    perror("bind() failed");
    unlink(SERVER_PATH);
    exit(0);
}

if((rc = listen(sfd, 10))<0)
{
    perror("listen() failed");
    exit(0);
}

printf("Ready for client connect().\n");

nsfd = accept(sfd, NULL, NULL);
if (nsfd < 0)
{
    perror("accept() failed");
    unlink(SERVER_PATH);
    exit(0);
}
/*rc = setsockopt(nsfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVLOWAT,(char *)&length, sizeof(length));
if (rc < 0)
{
    perror("setsockopt(SO_RCVLOWAT) failed");
    unlink(SERVER_PATH);
    exit(0);
}*/
recv(nsfd,buffer,200,0);
printf("the data recieved from client is %s\n",buffer);

struct iovec iov[1];
struct msghdr msg;

iov[0].iov_base = (char*)0;
iov[0].iov_len=0;
msg.msg_iov=iov;
msg.msg_iovlen=1;
msg.msg_name=(caddr_t)0;
msg.msg_control=(caddr_t)&fd;
msg.msg_controllen=sizeof(fd);
if(recvmsg(nsfd,&msg,0)<0)
{
    perror("recvmsg error:");
    unlink(SERVER_PATH);
    exit(0);
}
```

any one please let me know what can i do to solve the error..

Comment: Please accept answers to your previous questions. If you do that, people will more likely be willing to help you out.

Comment: I don't see `SCM_RIGHTS` anywhere in your code. As far as I know it's a necessary part of this...

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, fd will point to an integer that is unique within a process but quite useless outside of that process.  What exactly are you trying to achieve?  If you're trying to reuse a file handle between two processes, you may want to look into creating a named pipe.

[Wikipedia info on Named Pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe)

Edit: As Ben points out, I'm mistaken.  Thanks Ben.

Comment: [`man 7 unix`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/unix) says "Ancillary Messages

Ancillary data is sent and received using sendmsg(2) and recvmsg(2). For historical reasons the ancillary message types listed below are specified with a SOL_SOCKET type even though they are PF_UNIX specific. To send them set the cmsg_level field of the struct cmsghdr to SOL_SOCKET and the cmsg_type field to the type. For more information see cmsg(3).

SCM_RIGHTS"

Comment: "SCM RIGHTS - 
Send or receive a set of open file descriptors from another process. The data portion contains an integer array of the file descriptors. The passed file descriptors behave as though they have been created with dup(2).

Comment: Interesting, looking through the man page on recvmsg I didn't catch that detail.  Thanks for the pointer Ben.